# header and redirect in php

Tags: php, html

my problem is in my add-post page when i submit redirect isnt done and header()seems doesnt work

```
        public function insert($query){
        $insertRecord = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);
        if($insertRecord){
            header("Location:admin/index.php?msg=".urlencode('Record Added'));
            exit();
        }  else {
            die("Error : (".$this->link->errno.')'.$this->link->error);
        }
    }

        if($title == "" || $body == "" || $category == "" || $author == ""){
        $error = "please fill all required fields";
    }  else {
        $query = "insert into posts(category,title,body,author,tags) values ('$category','$title','$body','$author','$tags')";
        $insertRecord = $db->insert($query);
    }
```

Comment: Try header( 'Location: $url' );

Comment: @IvanBolnikh header('Location: admin/index.php?msg='.urlencode('Record Added')); but doesnt work too

Comment: When a form is properly filled, is the record added to the database? What happens in the browser?

Comment: @BeetleJuice added to DB but it doesnt redirect

Comment: Did browser recieve header 'Localtion: ...'?

Comment: @BeetleJuice no

Comment: If the record is added to the DB, but browser does not receive the header, it's very likely because you are setting the header after some content has already been sent to the browser. What's in the error log?

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: admin/index.php?msg='.urlencode('Record Added'));
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining why you solution will work? All I see is you added a whitespace and replaced `"` by `'`